# Having problems with nonlinear regression in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
attenuation = data.frame(km =      
c(0,0,0.4,0.4,0.8,0.8,1.2,1.2,1.6,1.6,2,2,2.4,2.4,2.8,2.8,3.2,3.2,3.6,3.6,4, 
4,4.4,4.4,4.8,4.8,5.2,5.2,5.6,5.6,6,6,6.4,6.4,6.8,6.8,7.2,7.2,7.6,7.6,8,8, 
11.7,11.7,13,13), edna = c(76000,20000,0,0,6000,0,0,6880,10700,0,6000,
0,0,0,0,0,0,6000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6310,0,6000,6000,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,6000,0,0,0,0))

#This worked great for a linear regression
ggplot(attenuation, aes(x = km, y = edna)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
xlab("Distance from Cage (km)") +
ylab("eDNA concentration (gene sequence/Liter)")
```

But the linear regression doesn't seem to be a good fit (r squared =0.09). So I'd like to try something else.  I tried some other regressions also with poor fits, so I'd like to try a nonlinear regression.

I have researched this question on stack overflow and tried a number of different options, but nothing is working. The option I provide below makes the most sense-but I wonder if I have the formula wrong? Or if the start list needs to be modified?

For context I am trying to explore the relationship between river distance and concentration.

```
#This is not working for a nonlinear regression
ggplot(attenuation, aes(x = km, y = edna))+ 
geom_point() + 
stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*x^b', method.args=list (start = 
list(a = 1,b=1), se=FALSE))
```

I get the following error from r when I run the code for nls above
   Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
   variable lengths differ (found for '(se)')

Comment: Thank you-I edited and this is now reproducible

Answer (score 6):

You have 2 problems. First a missplaced ")" since `se=FALSE` is an argument to `stat_smooth=`, not `method.args=`:

```
ggplot(attenuation, aes(x = km, y = edna))+ 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method='nls', formula='y~a*x^b', method.args=list(start = 
     list(a=1, b=1)), se=FALSE)
```

But this will not work either because your model is impossible to fit to your data. Look at the equation. When x=0, y will equal 0. For values of x greater than 0, y will increase unless b is negative, but but then x=0 is Inf so the algorithm fails to try negative values. Since you have a decreasing relationship, you need to specify a function that is defined for x=0 and plausible starting values. This one parameter fits your data better than a linear function (it could also be defined as `a*(x + 1)^-1` which is essentially your function with 1 added to x so that it is defined at x=0:

```
ggplot(attenuation, aes(x = km, y = edna))+ 
   geom_point() + 
   stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a/(x + 1)', 
      method.args=list(start=list(a=50000)), se=FALSE)
```

[[image: One parameter[1]]

I picked 50000 by splitting the difference between 20,000 and 76,000. The final estimate is about 20,000. You can bend the curve more sharply by adding a second parameter, but you have so many 0 values it may be too much depending on what you are trying to communicate:

```
ggplot(attenuation, aes(x = km, y = edna))+ 
   geom_point() + 
   stat_smooth(method='nls', formula='y~a*(1+x)^b', method.args=list(start = 
      list(a=50000, b=-1)), se=FALSE)
```

[image: Two parameters]

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @dcarlson's answer. You've got a pretty small data set here (a total of 11 non-zero data points, two of which fall on top of each other) so you probably shouldn't push any conclusions too hard. The first two points are definitely large, and there *might* be a mild declining trend after that, but beyond that you can't say too much.

If you want to do the power-law fit you have to displace the zero-km data point from the origin. I've done it by adding 0.1 to the x values. **This is an arbitrary choice on my part and should be thought about carefully on your end ...**  (note that there's a large difference in the results if you add 0.1 as I did or 1 as @dcarlson did). I also had to put in more reasonable starting values, which I did by fitting a log-log linear regression (`lm(log(edna) ~ log(km+0.1), data=attenuation)`) and extracting the coefficients (which were approximately 4 and -1.5).

```
ggplot(attenuation, aes(x = km, y = edna))+ 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*(x+0.1)^b',
              method.args=list (start = list(a = exp(4),b=-1.5)), se=FALSE)
```

You can also do this slightly more efficiently with a log-link Gaussian GLM as follows (you still need to displace the x-values from zero).  I also added some code to disambiguate the repeated points.

```
ggplot(attenuation, aes(x = km, y = edna))+ 
   stat_sum() + 
   geom_smooth(method="glm", formula=y~log(x+0.1),
          method.args=list(family=gaussian(link="log"),
                           start=c(4,-1.5)))+
   scale_size(breaks=c(1,2),range=c(1,3))
```

Comment: I appreciate the help from both of you. I agree that I can't really make any major conclusions from the data, but your insight is very helpful